# Função JS utilizando o jQuery bugando com o Foundation 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

Estou gerando um número aleatório ao clicar sobre um botão e após gerar este número insiro como sendo o `value` de um `input`. Porém, ao clicar no botão tudo segue normalmente o valor é gerado, tanto é que uso a função `alert()` para verificar se realmente está sendo gerado o número. O script gera o número consigo colocar no input que eu quero, mas após o `value` deste `input` ser alterado a pagina dá um reload. Não consigo identificar o responsável por esse reload. Estou usando jQuery e o framework Foudation 5.

Segue no Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r4dL5s0f/1/

O botão a qual eu clico para fazer essa tarefa é este abaixo `Carta Aleatória`:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para confirmar o funcionamento do script joquei o valor dentro do botão. Mas, mesmo assim a pagina dá um reload sozinha. Botão com o valor:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que o problema é que o seu botão é uma ancora:

```
<a href="" class="button tiny carta_aleatoria">Carta Aleatória</a>
```

precisa fazer `preventDefault()`

```
$(".carta_aleatoria").click(function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r4dL5s0f/2/

Já agora, talvez queira ter esse gerador de numero aleatório dentro da função?

```
$(".carta_aleatoria").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var numero = Math.floor((Math.random() * 895) + 1);
    alert(numero);
    $(this).empty().text(numero);
});
```

Comment: Deu certo, tava vacilando só com a ancora mesmo. vlw

Comment: Desculpas é por que quando marquei como certa tinha que esperar seis minutos e acabei me esquecendo. Obrigado novamente!